# Unable to display the Array contents present inside of an Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

For some reason i am not able to display the Array contents present inside of an Array though i have them.

Here is the code attached

```
render() {
 {
 var data ={
   value : "dff",
   provider: [{
   0:[{name: 'Rishan'},{name: 'kishan'},{name: 'jishan'},{name: 'mishan'},{name: 'fishan'}]
   }]
 }
 data.provider.map((i) => {
     i.map((j) => {
       return (
         <div>
         <h1>{i.value}</h1>
         <h1>{j.name}</h1>
         </div>
       );
     })
    })
    }
   }
   }
```

Now, I am trying to display the contents present inside the 0th index of the provider array

i.e

it has to print
   'Rishan', 'kishan', 'jishan' etc...

The present code is  displaying the [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what you did wrong: _You may have returned `undefined`_. Try `return`ing something in your `render()` method.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts  How can it return undefined when i have my contents there..

Comment: There is nothing specific to ES6 in this question. It's an ES5 question as much as it is an ES6 question.

Comment: Please understand how [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return something, if you don't put a return statement, then JavaScript will return undefined

```
render() {
 {
 var data ={
   value : "dff",
   provider: [{
   0:[{name: 'Rishan'},{name: 'kishan'},{name: 'jishan'},{name: 'mishan'},{name: 'fishan'}]
   }]
 }
 return data.provider.map((i) => {
     i[0].map((j) => {
       return (
         <div>
         <h1>{i.value}</h1>
         <h1>{j.name}</h1>
         </div>
       );
     })
    })
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: edited my answer. you need to use `i[0]` instead of `i`

Answer (score 1):

Its because your render function does not return valid jsx. wrap your entire content inside a div. else it wont work

```
 render() {
{
 var data ={
  value : "dff",
  provider: [{
  0:[{name: 'Rishan'},{name: 'kishan'},{name: 'jishan'},{name: 'mishan'},
 {name: 'fishan'}]
     }]
 }
return(<div>
 {data.provider.map((i) => {
    i[0].map((j) => {
      return (
        <div>
       <h1>{i.value}</h1>
       <h1>{j.name}</h1>
       </div>
     );
   })}</div>);
})
}
}
}
```